# How can I mount VHDX file using powershell properly?

Tags: windows, powershell, ntfs

I'm trying to automate process of mounting a particular *.vhdx file to Windows Server 2012r2.
When I'm mounting file manualy by GUI everything works just fine. The problem occure when I'm mounting file using *Mount-DiskImage* Powershell CmdLet. At first glance mounting ends successfuly but when I trying to create a file inside disk V:\ (which is the mounted VHDX in my case) I got an error about lack of permissions. I was thinking that somehow it' caused by wrong owning of folders, files and the disk itself, so I run :

> takeown /f V:\ /a /r /d Y

(...to reset all the permissions and grant them to Administrators.)

And what do you think? Yes. It didn't worked out. Then I checked SDDL string of V:\ in both cases of mounting VHDX (manually and with Powershell CmdLet) and it's turned out that they are absolutly the same (O:BAG:DUD:AI(A;ID;FA;;;WD)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)).
I can't find any reason why two of this methods give me different results. And I also can't find any visible difference in any properties of disk V:\ . 
Do you have any suggestions? Any ideas would be helpfull!

Thanks in advance for your time guys.

Comment: I can't test this, but maybe you have better luck with Mount-VHD? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848551.aspx

Comment: @Swonkie Unfortunately I can't use Mount-VHD CmdLet becouse Windows Server is a Virtual Host itself. So I can't install the Hyper-V role (using "sane" methods that doesn't enclude "peculiar" tricks like [this](http://linux-freebsd.ru/virtualizatsiya/hyper-v-virtualizatsiya/oshibka-nizkourovnevaya-obolochka-uzhe-zapushhena-pri-dobavlenii-roli-hyper-v-v-windows-server-2012-r2/)) on it and therefore the library that encludes this CmdLet isn't available for me.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to mount and to write to the mounted image?

Comment: @briantist "Mount-Diskimage -ImagePath \\$hostVHD\vhd\vhdx.vhdx" Nothing sofisticated. Previosly I used to add -Access parameter, but then I understude that it's thoughtfull only for "readonly" permission. P.S. $hostVHD is just an IP adress of Samba Server wich stores the VHDX file. P.P.S. To test availability of mounted disk I'm using Test-Path V: (wich is $True in both cases) and then I simply create new folder/file using GUI.

Comment: Have you tried copying the VHDX local? If so, does it work to write at that point? Is it possible you don't have permission on the share? I know you said it worked in GUI; maybe it's an elevation issue?

Comment: @briantist The VHDX file unfortunately larger then whole disk space on Windows Server. But I'll try to create new VHDX file locally and mount it with powershell and GUI. P.S All previous processes was executed under Builtin Administrator's profile/rights. P.P.S Also I CAN reach my goal using DISKPART but it's inconvinient to use in powershell script and not the case of this topic, though it might somehow pinpoint to the right path of thinking.